# Can the performance in SQL Server be boosted by index partitioning without the table partitioning

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I don't want to restructure the entire table, I merely want a boost on a couple of indexes. Will it work if I do not add `ON MyPartitionScheme(MyPartitionColumn)` to the TABLE, but will only add it to the proper index(es)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, yes, it can and the performance improves, although not as drastically.

It appears that the effect of applying the partition scheme on the table itself is essentially partitioning its primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is only one alternative for performance tuning for a database table.

If you could share us the execution plan for your queries that require performance tuning, we can try to fit the best option.

Maybe you have a missing index? Or maybe an invalid use of functions in WHERE clause could cause the problems.